# Why does a Groovy script hang indefinitely after throwing an exception using the assert statement?

Tags: groovy

I have a `verify.groovy` script that executes multiple Groovy scripts using the `evaluate()` function. One of the scripts, `first-check.groovy`, intentionally throws an exception using the `assert` statement. However, instead of exiting gracefully with the error message, the `verify.groovy` script seems to hang indefinitely and never completes.

Here's the code for `verify.groovy`:

```
[
  'first-check.groovy',
  'second-check.groovy'
].each {
  evaluate(basedir.toPath().resolve(it).toFile())
  println String.format('Verified with %s - OK', it)
}
```

And the code for `first-check.groovy`:

```
assert 1 == 2
true
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" Assertion failed: 

assert 1 == 2
         |
         false

        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.assertFailed(InvokerHelper.java:432)

<--- Hang here until I interrupt the process by Ctrl+C or command+C
```

Why does the script hang indefinitely instead of completing with the error message, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think, you must call the result of the `evaluate()`, like so `evaluate().call()`

Comment: @injecteer Thank for the suggestion, but it didn't help. The process still hangs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception handling in `each` and alike methods is tricky, so you have to catch and re-throw the exception manually:

```
String first = '''\
assert 1 == 2 
true'''
String second = '''\
assert true
true'''

[ first, second ].eachWithIndex{ it, ix ->
  try{
    def res = evaluate it
    println "Verified $ix with $res"
  }catch( Throwable t ){
    println "Check $ix failed miserably: $t"
    throw t // << re-throw!
  }
}

println 'end reached'
```

In this case you will see this in the console:

```
Check 0 failed miserably: Assertion failed: 

assert 1 == 2
         |
         false
Assertion failed: 

assert 1 == 2
         |
         false

    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:10)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:8)
```

If you comment the re-throw line out, the output will be:

```
Check 0 failed miserably: Assertion failed: 

assert 1 == 2
         |
         false

Verified 1 with true
end reached
```

With that said, the better option to iterate through the scripts would be to use a plain `for` loop:

```
int ix = 0
for( it in [ first, second ] ){
  def res = evaluate it
  println "Verified $ix with $res"
  ix++
}
```

In this case the exception with be propagated without blocking.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! However, I still have problems with hangs. I applied your solution with re-throw exception, but it didn't help, but if I change `throw t` with function `fail(t)` it starts working.

Comment: The solution with iteration through the scripts didn't help either.

Comment: Maybe it worth to mention, that I run groovy scripts using `groovy-maven-plugin` and I'm afraid the problem could be in the plugin itself. WDYT? Apparently your solution is correct.